# Webpack configuration to create multiple files

Tags: html-webpack-plugin, webpack-2

I am trying to have two css files (light & dark themes) generated separately so I can build a theme switcher for my app to load either style based on user preference. Can't seem to get this to work without errors.

Actually the files are created as expected but I only want one of them injected into my doc head, everything works as long as I allow both to be injected.

```
config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
'dg-light': './src/dg-light.ts',
'dg-dark': './src/dg-dark.ts',
'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
};


new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
template: './src/public/index.html',
chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
chunks: ['vendor', 'polyfills', 'dg-light']
//excludeChunks:  ['dg-dark']
})
```

I was trying to influence which files get injected into the head using the chunks or excludeChunks option but I keep getting an error when i use these options.

webpackJsonp is not defined error